# Suggestion for a time grid?

Tags: vb.net, time, colors, grid

In VB.NET I'm looking to build a "Time" grid very similar to the Time Restriction grid of the Parental Section of Windows: http://www.thinkbroadband.com/images/guides/time-restrictions.png

It needs to toggle between 2 colors on cell-click

I've played around with One-Cell = One-Label and it kinda works but, like the Windows Time Restriction grid, I'd like to have the labels change colors if I move over the label **whilst** having the left button pressed (and not only on label click).

Here is what I currently have:

```
Private Sub ColorToggle(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles Label1.Click, Label2.Click, Label3.Click 'etc..
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        sender.backcolor = If(sender.backcolor = SystemColors.Control, Color.LightGreen, SystemColors.Control)
    End If
End Sub
```

Since the sender stays the same when I hover the labels (sender = label I've originally clicked on), this code doesn't work for my purpose.

I'm looking for suggestions!

Thanks :)

Comment: An unbound datagridview control may do the trick. The cells are all addressable. You can address the cells at load to change the color or you can use the cellformat event. You can bind the grid to your own class or a datatable. Click events are available.

Comment: @rheitzman  Any chance you'd have an example of such solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on a control and you hold the mouse button down, this control captures the following mouse events, so that you won't get events from the other lables when moving the mouse over them.

The trick is to set `label.Capture = False`.

Lets define colors:

```
Private ReadOnly selectedColor As Color = Color.Blue
Private ReadOnly unselectedColor As Color = Color.White
```

And Booleans storing the current state of our operations

```
Private isSelecting As Boolean = False
Private isUnselecting As Boolean = False
```

(All four as fields of the form class)

Now lets write these three event handlers:

```
Private Sub Label_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'This event starts selecting/unselecting

    Dim label = DirectCast(sender, Label)
    label.Capture = False '<=== THIS IS IMPORTANT!
    If label.BackColor = selectedColor Then
        isUnselecting = True
    Else
        isSelecting = True
    End If
    SelectLabel(label)
End Sub

Private Sub Label_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    'This event stops selecting/unselecting

    isSelecting = False
    isUnselecting = False
End Sub

Private Sub Label_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    SelectLabel(DirectCast(sender, Label))
End Sub
```

And we need this procedure that selects or unselects the labels:

```
Private Sub SelectLabel(label As Label)
    If isSelecting Then
        label.BackColor = selectedColor
    ElseIf isUnselecting Then
        label.BackColor = unselectedColor
    End If
End Sub
```

That's it!

---

Footnote: I have created the lables like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Const w As Integer = 50, h As Integer = 50

    For x = 1 To 10
        For y = 1 To 10
            Dim lbl As New Label() With {
                .Location = New Point(x * w, y * h),
                .Size = New Size(w, h),
                .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
                .BackColor = unselectedColor
            }
            AddHandler lbl.MouseDown, AddressOf Label_MouseDown
            AddHandler lbl.MouseUp, AddressOf Label_MouseUp
            AddHandler lbl.MouseEnter, AddressOf Label_MouseEnter
            Controls.Add(lbl)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for a good suggestion, my layout has 4 rows of 94 labels (basically one label = 15min) and there are 4 days. I've implemented your soilution but it seems kinda slow and some labels are not highlighted when the mouse move (even slowly). In order to make it work I need to move VERY VERY slowly.
Any tip on how to boost performace?

Comment: My test implementation runs very fast. Probably something else is slowing it down. Try to implement my solution on a new blank form. Don't place any controls on it and use the code I have shown in my footnote to populate it. Adapt the numbers to get the 94 x 4 labels. Just as a test.

Comment: I was testing over RDP, that's why it was slow. Testing locally works great indeed. Accepting your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this isn't homework...

```
Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    Dim i As Integer
    With dgv
        .ColumnCount = 0
        .DataSource = Nothing
        .Columns.Add("Day", "Day")
        For i = 0 To 23
            .Columns.Add(i, i)
            .Columns(.Columns.Count - 1).Width = 30
        Next
        For i = 1 To 7
            .Rows.Add({i})
        Next

    End With
End Sub

Private Sub dgv_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgv.CellClick
    dgv.CurrentCell.Style.BackColor = Color.Blue
End Sub
```

---

Here is a drag version:

```
Private Sub dgv_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles dgv.MouseUp
    For Each cell As DataGridViewCell In dgv.SelectedCells
        If cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Blue Then
            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.White
        Else
            cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Blue
        End If
    Next
    dgv.ClearSelection()
End Sub
```

Comment: .Rows.Add({Format(CDate("1/" & i & "/1990"), "dddd")}) for day names

Comment: hehe I'm 36yo so no, not for homework ;) Thanks for the tips, very usefull to put me in the right direction. The problem with the datagrid is that when selecting horizontaly it works but horizontaly AND veritcally (diagonally basically) the grid creates a "rectangle" selection. I need to have only the cells "hovered on" selected..

Comment: The dgv has a Hover event but IMO it would not be user friendly - difficult to code. Try the drag version above (remove the CellClick event.) "Drag" in this case is left mouse down and on mouse up the selected cells are toggled. The toggle one cell "click" for a mouse down/up.